# HTML5 responsive canvas: resizing the browser canvas draw disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I want to make a responsive canvas using size in percentage and once user will resize the window the canvas adjust relatively.
I am able to scale the canvas by using below code but the only problem is as i scale the window size the mouse drawing disappear.

```
<style>
body{margin:0px;padding:0px;background:#a9a9a9;}
#main{
display:block;
width:80%;
padding:50px 10%;
height:300px;
} 
canvas{display:block;background:#fff;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main" role="main">
<canvas id="paint" width="100" height="100">
< !-- Provide fallback -->
</canvas>
</div> 

<script>

var c = document.getElementById('paint');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var x = null;
var y;

c.onmousedown = function(e){
x = e.pageX - c.offsetLeft;
y = e.pageY - c.offsetTop;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x,y);

}

c.onmouseup = function(e){
x=null;

}


c.onmousemove = function(e){
if(x==null) return;
x = e.pageX - c.offsetLeft;
y = e.pageY - c.offsetTop; 
ctx.lineTo(x,y);
ctx.stroke();

}

$(document).ready( function(){
//Get the canvas &
var c = $('#paint');

var container = $(c).parent();

//Run function when browser resizes
$(window).resize( respondCanvas );

function respondCanvas(){ 
    c.attr('width', $(container).width() ); //max width
    c.attr('height', $(container).height() ); //max height

    //Call a function to redraw other content (texts, images etc)
}

//Initial call 
respondCanvas();

}); 


</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517783/preventing-canvas-clear-when-resizing-window

Comment: use this library, and draw the screen on each frame: http://georgealways.github.io/gee/

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23128583/1265753

Answer (score 10):

**Dealing with contents when resizing a canvas**

If you resize the canvas, the drawn content is always erased.  That's how canvas behaves.

You can either redraw the content after resizing or you can save the content as image data and restore after resizing (see canvas.toDataURL).

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/V6SVz/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    // draw some content
    ctx.lineWidth=3;
    ctx.fillStyle="blue";
    ctx.strokeStyle="red";
    ctx.rect(50,50,100,50);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.font="14px Verdana";
    ctx.fillStyle="white";
    ctx.fillText("Scale Me",65,75);

    function saveResizeAndRedisplay(scaleFactor){

        // save the canvas content as imageURL
        var data=canvas.toDataURL();

        // resize the canvas
        canvas.width*=scaleFactor;
        canvas.height*=scaleFactor;

        // scale and redraw the canvas content
        var img=new Image();
        img.onload=function(){
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        }
        img.src=data;

    }

    $("#resizer").click(function(){ saveResizeAndRedisplay(1.5); });

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <button id="resizer">Click to resize the canvas</button><br/>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=200 height=150></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
c.attr('width', $(container).width() ); //max width
c.attr('height', $(container).height() ); //max height
```

the above code is equivalent to `clearRect` which is used to clear the canvas .so you cannot adjust the width and height if you want to retain what was drawn previously.
as a solution you can create a new canvas with required width and draw the content of previous  canvas using `drawImage(c)` c is the canvas object .then you have to delete the canvas

Comment: Thanks So is there any option to first save the canvas drawing and then set c.attr().. or any other way to set dynamic responsive width/height to canvas.

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same issue that your are facing in mu application, and after reading about it i came to this conclusion that the behavior of the canvas element is such that it clears itself after re-sizing, the only fix for this is to add a listener for the window re-size event and redraw the canvas when the event if fired.

```
$(window).resize(function(e) {
// function to redraw on the canvas
});



$(document).ready(function(e){
    var c = $('#example'); // getting the canvas element
    var ct = c.get(0).getContext('2d');
    var container = $(c).parent();
    $(window).resize( respondCanvas ); //handling the canvas resize
    function respondCanvas(){ 
        // makign the canvas fill its container
        c.attr('width', $(container).width() ); //max width
        c.attr('height', ($(container).height() -20 )); //max height
    }
    respondCanvas();
    make_image('images/india.png',1,1);
}
```

Hope it helps.

[Source](http://ameijer.nl/2011/08/resizable-html5-canvas/)

Comment: Please give the source when you copy code from a website.

Answer (score 2):

below is the code what I was trying to do:

```
<head>
<style>
       
#main {
    display:block;
    width:80%;
    height:300px;
    background:#e0e0e0;
}

canvas {
    display:block;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid red;
}
</style>

<script>

    $(function(){
    
    var container=document.getElementById("main");
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    // draw some content
    //alert(canvas.width);
    
    var w=$(container).width();
    var h=$(container).height();
    
    $(window).resize( saveResizeAndRedisplay );
    function saveResizeAndRedisplay(){

        // save the canvas content as imageURL
        var data=canvas.toDataURL();

        // resize the canvas
        canvas.width = $(container).width();
        canvas.height = $(container).height();
        //alert($(container).width());
    
        // scale and redraw the canvas content
        var img=new Image();
        img.onload=function(){
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height);
        }
        img.src=data;

    }
    
    saveResizeAndRedisplay();
    
    }); 
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="main" role="main">
 <canvas id="canvas" width=200 height=150></canvas>
</div>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = null;
var y;

canvas.onmousedown = function(e){
x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x,y);
}

canvas.onmouseup = function(e){
x=null;
}


canvas.onmousemove = function(e){
if(x==null) return;
x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop; 
ctx.lineTo(x,y);
ctx.stroke();
}
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've created a jQuery plugin that handles HTML5 canvas resizing. It was built to bridge the gap between mobile and desktop users. It is still a WIP but it is extensible, and has some basic drawing functions built in.

http://trsanders.github.io/responsive-sketchpad/

Answer (score 0):

I use this method:

```
var context = document.getElementById('paint').getContext('2d');
var canvas = context.canvas;

function responsive(width){
    var p = width / canvas.width;
    canvas.width *= p;
    canvas.height *= p;

    var scaleFactor = context.scaleFactor || 1;
    context.scale(p * scaleFactor, p * scaleFactor);
    context.scaleFactor = p * scaleFactor;
}

var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 735px)");
mq.addListener(applyChanges);
applyChanges();

function applyChanges(){
    if(!mq)
        responsive(350);
    else
        responsive(735);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. My solution is using CSS3's property zoom to the parent's container of the canvas:

```
<div id="parent_div">
    <div id="constructor_div">
         <canvas width="600" height="900">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    constructor_zoom();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        constructor_zoom();
    });

    function constructor_zoom()
    {
        var parent_width = $('#parent_div').width();
        var item_width = $('#constructor_div').width();
        var coef = 0.1;

        $('.constructor_image').css('zoom', parent_width/item_width - coef);
    }
</script>
```

coef - coefficient to make indents of the canvas from the parent's borders. You may make it zero.

I hope it helps to somebody :-)

Comment: Not sure Zoom is a CSS attribute