# How to solve ChartJs canvas height with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts

I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34772957/how-to-make-canvas-responsive) as well as other solutions. But nothing is working as I want. On a ChartJS pie-charts canvas, when I am using a height attribute, it's working fine. Like:

```
<canvas id="a_Pie_Chart" height="400"></canvas>
```

But when I am removing the height attribute and trying to define it using CSS it doesn't seem to work. Like:

**HTML:**

```
<canvas id="a_Pie_Chart" class="chartCanvas"></canvas>
```

**CSS:**

```
.chartCanvas {
  height : 400px;
}
```

It is to add that in Javascript of the chartjs I am using:

```
options: {
   responsive: true,
   responsiveAnimationDuration: 500,
   mainAspectRatio : false
   }
```

and My Pie chart has **too much (minimum 20)** labels and data. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Why is this a problem? What's wrong with just using the HTML? Resizing via CSS could be difficult, because it's rendering in elements that all need to also be resized. The `height` *attribute* is there because it's parsed by the function when asked to populate the canvas - the `chartjs` has no way of knowing your CSS though, so that can only possibly apply after it's rendered everything (often too late in the case of SVGs). I'd advise creating a new canvas element instead via JS if you want to change the size, and deleting the old one.

Comment: predefining with html isn't worth. Because I have too much data. So, I have to take a large value of heigh which looks odd on desktop.

Comment: Just predefine the height via HTML. If you want to create the element via JS, too, however, simply do `let canvas = document.createElement("canvas"); ... stuff to set the contents ... canvas.setAttribute("height", "400");` If your problem is it looks too tall on the screen, try doing `maxheight: 200px; overflow: scroll;` in CSS.