# JS loop skips to last rectangle (using canvas) drawn on the screen

Tags: javascript, loops, canvas, rect

I'm fairly new with OOP and classes but was experimenting with it, while trying to create a method that would randomly create triangles on my HTML5 canvas.

The problem is that I can only see the last rectangle produced on the loop. All the other rectangles are not shown on the screen. Here is my code.

```js
class Animations{       
   constructor(){}
    //Background animation
    backgroundAnimation(x,y,height,width){
        this._x       = x;
        this._y       = y;
        this._height  = height;
        this._width   = width;
        let canvas    = document.querySelector('canvas');
        canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight; 

        let c         = canvas.getContext('2d');
        c.beginPath;
        c.rect(this._x,this._y,this._width,this._height);
        c.fillStyle = 'blue';
        c.fill()
        c.stroke();
    }        
}

var animations = new Animations();

window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
    for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
        let x = Math.floor(Math.random()*100+50);
        let y = Math.floor(Math.random()*100+50);
        animations.backgroundAnimation(x,y,20,20);
    }
});
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are resizing the canvas, each time you draw on it, which causes it to clear.

See [HTML5 responsive canvas: resizing the browser canvas draw disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878377/html5-responsive-canvas-resizing-the-browser-canvas-draw-disappear/23128583#23128583) and [Preventing Canvas Clear when Resizing Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517783/preventing-canvas-clear-when-resizing-window)

If you really want to resize it each time, then you'll have to come up with a way to store the things you drew on it, and re-draw.

Alternatively, if don't need to resize it, then simply create one instance of your `Animations` class, and do the resizing in the constructor:

```
<body>
  <canvas></canvas>
  <script>
    class Animations{
      constructor(){
        let canvas    = document.querySelector('canvas');
        canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        this.c = canvas.getContext('2d');
      }

      //Background animation
      backgroundAnimation(x,y,height,width){
        this._x       = x;
        this._y       = y;
        this._height  = height;
        this._width   = width;

        this.c.beginPath();
        this.c.rect(this._x,this._y,this._width,this._height);
        this.c.fillStyle = 'blue';
        this.c.fill();
        this.c.stroke();
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
      const animations = new Animations();

      for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
        let x = Math.floor(Math.random()*100+50);
        let y = Math.floor(Math.random()*100+50);
        animations.backgroundAnimation(x,y,20,20);
      }});
  </script>
</body>
```

Note you can then store a reference to the context as a property of the class `this.c` so that it can be accessed from the `backgroundAnimation()` method.

Comment: thank you very much for the clear explanation and recommendations for defining the context and cavas in the constructor. It makes a lot of sense to do so. Once again thank you :)

Comment: You're very welcome! Glad I could help.