# Set Canvas size using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have the following code in html:

```
<canvas  id="myCanvas" width =800 height=800>
```

I want, instead of specifying the `width` as `800`, to call the JavaScript function `getWidth()`  to get the width e.g.

```
 <canvas  id="myCanvas" width =getWidth() height=800>
```

What is the correct syntax to do it? Because what I'm doing doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe this help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331052/how-to-resize-html-canvas-element

Comment: you can relate to this post for a "fit to screen" 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664785/html5-canvas-resize-to-fit-window

Comment: Did you mean `<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="800">` and `<canvas id="myCanvas" width="getWidth()" height="800">`. Is that a typo or an error in the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize html canvas element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331052/how-to-resize-html-canvas-element)

Answer (score 86):

You can set the width like this :

```
function draw() {
  var ctx = (a canvas context);
  ctx.canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
  ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  //...drawing code...
}
```

Comment: Draw function is not best place for this code. Use onresize with no problems.

Answer (score 48):

```
function setWidth(width) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");  
  canvas.width = width;
}
```

Comment: In here, the width must be just one number, without unit. correct: "100", not correct: "100px"

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
var setCanvasSize = function() {
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To set the width and height of canvas you can use width and height object property of canvas to set width & height.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
canvas.width = 350     // 350px
canvas.height = 200    // 200px
```

```css
#canvas {
    background-color:blue
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var w = window,
d = document,
e = d.documentElement,
g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
xS = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
yS = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;
alert(xS + ' × ' + yS);
```

document.write('')

works for iframe and well.

Comment: document.write('<canvas id="myCanvas" width="'+xS+'" height="'+yS+'" ></canvas>')

Answer (score -10):

You can also use this script , just change the height and width

```
<canvas id="Canvas01" width="500" height="400" style="border:2px solid #FF9933; margin-left:10px; margin-top:10px;"></canvas>

   <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas01");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Comment: OP has evidently gotten this far already. I think he/she wants to resize the canvas in the JS code.