# How do I dynamically scale the HTML5 <canvas> element?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I want to resize the canvas element by dragging at corners.

share any hints.

thanks

[image]

Comment: Look at the answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331052/how-to-resize-html-canvas-element

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to change the size by assigning width and height attributes using numbers:

```
canvasNode.width  = 200; // in pixels
canvasNode.height = 100; // in pixels
```

At least it works for me. Make sure you don't assign strings (e.g., "2cm", "3in", or "2.5px"), and don't mess with styles.

Actually this is a publicly available knowledge — you can read all about it in the HTML canvas spec — it is very small and unusually informative. This is the whole DOM interface:

```
interface HTMLCanvasElement : HTMLElement {
           attribute unsigned long width;
           attribute unsigned long height;

  DOMString toDataURL();
  DOMString toDataURL(in DOMString type, [Variadic] in any args);

  DOMObject getContext(in DOMString contextId);
};
```

As you can see it defines 2 attributes width and height, and both of them are unsigned long.

With css3 also you can do it set property

```
resize:both;
```