# Bootstrap grid not working with canvas

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, chart.js

I'm trying to place a chart using Chart.js on a row with `span6`. Chart.js uses `<canvas>` and needs a `height` and `width` property. I've set the `height` to what I need and the `width` to 100% but it doesn't stretch to fill the div which is set to `span6`.

Any ideas?

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 20px;">
  <div class="span6">
    <div id="daily">
      <canvas id="daily-chart" width="100%" height="400px"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 16):

I managed to solve your problem!

**Please check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/achudars/k8Mdw/).**

Try resizing the panels to see it in action.

Basically, you call a function that responds to the resize of the window:

```
$(window).resize(respondCanvas);
```

that triggers a fetch of the width and height of the parent element that it is encapsulated in and then redraws your chart.

```
function respondCanvas() {
    c.attr('width', jQuery("#daily").width());
    c.attr('height', jQuery("#daily").height());
    //Call a function to redraw other content (texts, images etc)
    myNewChart = new Chart(ct).Bar(data, options);
}
```

You can adjust all tiny bits like your own IDs, classes, width and heights.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you mark this as answered if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

in the JavaScript file where you add all the options for the chart

```
new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options );

//Boolean - If we want to override with a hard coded scale
    scaleOverride : true,
```

Comment: also check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894607/how-do-i-dynamically-scale-the-html5-canvas-element

Comment: I previously set the options to null. To use them do I just create an options array? var options = [scaleOverride : true];?

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/
Line.defaults = { scaleOverride : true }

Comment: I had but I'm not sure how to implement it (I'm new to JS). Could you show me? I looked through the sample code but none of them implement options.

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately the chart still isn't stretching to fill the width of the div. That option just sets the scale of the data on the chart, not the size of the chart itself.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368477/dynamically-resize-canvas-window-with-javascript-jquery

Comment: No luck. It's still only responding to the canvas width option and not stretching 100%.

Comment: Maybe you can share your own jsFiddle and we can look at it?

Comment: It seems that canvas can't be set to 100% (has to be a specific value). The links you shared were useful - I'm going to have to adjust the size in the JS.