# Resize html canvas element with pure javascript

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I'm working on a game using only html5 canvas element and javascript. i need to be able to re-size it, but don't want to use any librarys

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331052/how-to-resize-html-canvas-element

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the width and height of the canvas by assigning it to a variable, and use the width and height properties.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("ID of canvas here");
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;
```

Comment: ...and keep in mind that resizing the canvas will automatically clear all its contents.  Therefore, you will have to redraw all the objects on your resized canvas.