# I'd like to change size of the canvas with data from input form

Tags: javascript, dom

I have two input forms - **Width**, **Height** and button - **submit**
When user enters values in form and presses the button I'd like to render on a same page **canvas** with user's dimensions.

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
    <form>
        <label for="enterWidthInput">Width:</label><br>
        <input type="number" id="enterWidthInput" name="widthInput"><br>

        <label for="enterHeightInput">Height:</label><br>
        <input type="number" id="enterHeightInput" name="heightInput"><br>

        <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>


<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

app.js:

```
let canvasElement =  document.getElementById("myCanvas");
let userInputHeight = document.getElementById("enterHeightInput");
let userInputWidth = document.getElementById("enterWidthInput");
let addParamCanvas = document.getElementById("submitButton");


function changeCanvas() {
    canvasElement.style.width = userInputWidth+"px";
    canvasElement.style.height = userInputHeight+"px";
}

addParamCanvas.addEventListener('click', changeCanvas);

$("#submitButton").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

css:

```
#app canvas {
    margin: auto;
}

#myCanvas {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

The problem is, I don't see any changes.

I tried different approaches:

- used JQuery,
- different method (POST, GET),
- different buttons,
- tried to save input data in different global variable,
- googled it

But can't find anything that will work with canvas and input form.

Comment: `userInputWidth` etc refers to the element. You want the value `userInputWidth.value`. [And also this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331052/how-to-resize-html-canvas-element): adding the dimensions to the canvas element in the markup and not the CSS would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
function changeCanvas() {
    canvasElement.style.width = userInputWidth.value+"px";
    canvasElement.style.height = userInputHeight.value+"px";
}
```

:)